# Keystroke activated add-on to slide window to other monitor with smooth transition?

Tags: windows-7, multi-monitor

I have a Windows 7 32 bit PC with a Matrox M9140 quad-head graphics card. Is there a way to slide the open window to the next monitor?

I know windows will let me move the window using <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> or <kbd>Left</kbd> but but this causes it to jump across: it is removed from the current screen and appears on the other screen. I would like a smooth sliding action for the transition if possible. I'm looking for a software solution to slide the window. Something activated with a key-combination such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> would be ideal Is this possible?

Comment: So you want a peice of software that automatically moves a window to a different monitor? What should trigger it, I.e. a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: I have integrated the info you provided in comments into your question. Next time please provide clarifications by [edit]ing the info into your question yourself. We also request you put some basic effort into properly punctuating and capitalizing your posts. We're interested it creating a lasting reference for others, not just clobbering together a post that gets by. This will benefit you too as the quality of responses you garner will be better than if you are lazy with your question formatting. Thanks for understanding.